# How to check whether mod_rewrite is enable on server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lightspeed

Currently I am using the hosting with **lightspeed** server. Hosting says `mod_rewrite` is enabled but I can't get my script working there. Whenever I try to access the URL, it returns **404 - not found** page.

I put the same codes at another server which is running with Apache. It's working over there. So I guess, it's the `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` issue.

But Hosting support is still insisting with me that their mod_rewrite is on, so I would like to know how can I check whether it's actually enabled or not.

I tried to check with `phpinfo()`, but no luck, I can't find `mod_rewrite` there, is it because they are using `lightspeed`?

Is there any way to check? Please help me out. Thank you.

**FYI:** my `.htaccess` code is

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I tried like this also

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But same result.

Comment: The simplest way to verify whether `mod-rewrite` is enabled is paste some random texts in your htaccess and then visit your site , you will get an internal server error if the module is enabled. Here is a quick `htaccess tutorial for beginners` I wrote a few months ago, https://helponnet.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/ hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 149):

from the command line, type

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

if the rewrite mode is already enabled, it will tell you so!

Comment: `sudo: a2enmod: command not found` NOT enabled.  ... Install via `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart server `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: will return "Module rewrite already enabled" if it's ok.

Answer (score 115):

1. To check if mod_rewrite module is enabled, create a new php file in your root folder of your WAMP server. Enter the following

   `phpinfo();`
2. Access your created file from your browser.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open a search. Search for 'mod_rewrite'. If it is enabled you see it as 'Loaded Modules'
4. If not, open httpd.conf (Apache Config file) and look for the following line.

   `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
5. Remove the pound ('#') sign at the start and save the this file.
6. Restart your apache server.
7. Access the same php file in your browser.
8. Search for 'mod_rewrite' again. You should be able to find it now.

Comment: I believe phpinfo() reports the _Apache_ Loaded Modules when PHP is itself being run as an Apache module. The OP states that PHP is running on Lightspeed, which has its own mod_rewrite compatible rewrite engine.

Comment: For the first step I had to enter: <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Note that this method will not work if you are running PHP as a CGI application (which is the case if `phpinfo()`’s “Server API” field shows “CGI/FastCGI”). `phpinfo()` won’t list the enabled modules. In that case, see [How to check for mod_rewrite on PHP CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18310183/578288).

Answer (score 98):

If you are using a virtual hosts configuration file, make sure the virtual host in question has the directive `AllowOverride All` somewhere like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
    <Directory "directory/of/your/.htaccess">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, this states to allow processing of all .htaccess directives.

Comment: Thanks. I owe you a Budweiser. <3

Comment: what does it mean the `...` in `<Directory ...>` ? What shall I put there? the directory where .htaccess is?

Comment: yes indeed, the ... should mention between quotes "..." the directory where .htaccess is

Comment: It had. I had the conf file copied from the server, and while I had changed the `ServerName`, I had not changed the directory name, after that and an apache restart it was ok.

Comment: RichardIf this answer worked for you and solved your problem you should mark it as correct and award @Jahmic his due.

Answer (score 27):

This works on CentOS:

```
$ sudo httpd -M |grep rewrite_module
```

Should output `rewrite_module (shared)`

Comment: This is the best way to do it on CentOS, assuming you have ssh access.  Thanks, @radtek!

Answer (score 19):

If apache_get_modules() is not recognized or no info about this module in phpinfo(); try to test mod rewrite by adding those lines in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ mod_rewrite.php
```

And mod_rewrite.php:

```
<?php echo "Mod_rewrite is activated!"; ?>
```

Answer (score 18):

console:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
    <Directory ...>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I've tried a lot to solve this and then when try this it works for me.
I have the last apache and ubuntu now.

Answer (score 16):

If

```
in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())
```

returns `true` then mod-rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Perfect one line solution to check rewrite module enabled or not via PHP codes.

Answer (score 16):

PHP's perdefined **`apache_get_modules()`** function returns a list of enabled modules. To check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled , you can run the following script on your server :

```
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

If the above example fails, you can verify mod-rewrite using your `.htaccess` file.

Create an `htaccess` file in the document root and add the following rewriteRule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^helloWorld/?$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Now visit http://example.com/HelloWorld , You will be internally forwarded to **/index.php** page of your site. Otherwise, if mod-rewrite is disabled , you will get a 500 Internel server error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i use 7.2, apache_get_modules got undefined. Do i have to restart apache2 after editing `.htaccess` ?

Comment: No you don't need to restart your server when using htaccess.

Answer (score 15):

you can do it on terminal, either:

```
apachectl -M
apache2ctl -M
```

taken from [2daygeek](https://www.2daygeek.com/cheat-sheet-for-apache2-commands-linux-mint-ubuntu-debian/)

Comment: In Debian 9, it does work but you must be logged in as root or use `sudo`

Answer (score 10):

If this code is in your .htaccess file (without the check for mod_rewrite.c)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and you can visit any page on your site with getting a 500 server error I think it's safe to say mod rewrite is switched on.

Comment: So you can access some pages on the site without a 500 error? That would generally mean if the .htaccess file is being read that mod_rewrite must be switched on. However the .htaccess might not be being read...try writing some nonsense characters at the top of your .htaccess file, this will cause the connection to die with a 500 server error if Apache is actually reading the file. If it is being read, could you give an example of a URL you think should work but doesn't?

Comment: the problem is, it's not apache server, it's lightspeed. I never get 500 error, all i get is 404 error. That's why I am doubting that .htaccess is not enable.

Comment: Most likely yes, I'd try putting the nonsense characters in to .htaccess and see if you get the 500 error when you go directly to a non-rewritten page (e.g. index.php). If not, it might be worth posting a new question asking how to enable .htaccess with Lightspeed

Answer (score 5):

You can use php function

```
      apache_get_modules
```

and check for mod_rewrite

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
</pre>
```

https://www.php.net/apache_get_modules

Comment: apache_get_modules() will only work if PHP is running as an Apache module. The OP states that PHP is running on Lightspeed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in linux system, you can check all enable modules for apache2(in my case) in the following folder:/etc/apache2/mods-available

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

to type: `ll -a`
if you want to check the available modules for php (in this case php 7 )
folder /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```

to type: `ll -a`

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but if you can edit your Apache configuration file to `AllowOverride All` from `AllowOverride None`

```
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: It is a good idea to tell the exact name and when possible the location of the file that need to be changed. It will be helpful for the newcomers. Thanks

Comment: It should also be kept in mind that the changes take effect only after you have restated your apache. thanks

Answer (score 4):

just make a new page and add this code

```
 <?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())) 
 $res = 'Module Available';
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A mod_rewrite availability check !</title></head>
<body>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $res"; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and run this page then find will able to know module is Available or not if not then you can ask to your hosting or if you want to enable it in local machine then check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enable rewrite module in wamp apache
https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and check the rewrite module option

Answer (score 4):

This code worked for me:

```
if (strpos(shell_exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l'), 'mod_rewrite') !== false) echo "mod_rewrite enabled";
else echo "mod_rewrite disabled";
```

Answer (score 4):

First you check if the module is installed

```
apachectl -M
```

It it does not shows on the list, you must activate it:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Now, restart your server and test

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check whether the file is there, by typing

`cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load`

The result line may not be commented starting with `#`

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a php file in root and add following code

```
<?php
if (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) {
    echo "mod_rewrite is enabled";
} else {
    echo "mod_rewrite is not enabled";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact problem, I solved it by clicking custom structure, then adding `/index.php/%postname%/` and it works

Hope this saves someone the stress that I went through finding what the heck was wrong with it.