# How to check for mod_rewrite on PHP CGI

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am on shared host and PHP is inatalled as CGI script and that is all the problem i am not able to find whether mod_rewrite if enable or not

`Note: I don't have any root level access so i can't much do with Shell.`

I have tried the following :
 
1) checked in [phpinfo()](http://www.nationalaudio.com.au.tmp.anchor.net.au/info.php) where i came to know about that this is the wrong place to look for in PHP-CGI.

2) I have tried getting it from apache_get_modules which agi does not work in PHP-CGI :(
 
3) I have tried :

```
if (strpos(shell_exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l'), 'mod_rewrite') !== false) {
    // mod_rewrite is enabled
}
```

which is asking for path to apache and i dont have this info SHELL cant reply to me and $_SERVER has nothing.
 
4) I have checked with `RewriteEngine On` in .htaccess and after this my site is throwing 500 Internal server error may be because of RewriteEngine is not there, but i need this is written to show someone.

Any body has any idea how to check get this DONE.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

With PHP CGI there is no easy way to find out whether mod_rewrite is available or not on the server.

So, you need to find out it by making a test call to the server. You can use the following steps for this method,

1. Create a directory named `mod_rewrite_test` on the server.
2. Add `.htaccess` file in this directory with the following code,

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mod_rewrite_test
    RewriteRule .* mod_rewrite_test.txt
    </IfModule>`

   a. first line tells apache to execute the below code only if mod_rewrite is available, 
   b. second line enables rewrite engine,
   c. third line sets rewrite base directory path which is from `DOCUMENT_ROOT` 
   d. forth line returns the content of `mod_rewrite_test.txt` file to any request sent to `mod_rewrite_test` directory.
3. Create a file named `mod_rewrite_test.txt` in the same directory. Write `ok` in this file and save it.
4. Now, using `CURL` in your php script, call the URL similar to,

   http://www.your-domain.com/mod_rewrite_test/test.php
   and check the response.

   So, as per our `.htaccess` code, if mod_rewrite is active and working on the server, 
   it will return the content of `mod_rewrite_test.txt` file i.e. `ok` even though the test.php file does not exists.

   Otherwise, it will return 404 - Page not found error.

Answer (score -3):

To check if mod_rewrite module is enabaled, create a new php file in your root folder of your server. Enter the following

```
echo phpinfo();
```

And access file in your browser.