# Permalink is not working after I moved my WordPress site from local to remote server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I was really struggling to find the answer. When I moved my WordPress site from localhost to remote server my links are not working. It showing that:

```
The requested URL /project/investment was not found on this server.
```

I don't know what is the problem. I searched a lot, but I cant find the correct solution. I have created the menubar using the html rather than the WordPress nav menu.

Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /newsite.in/project/
RewriteRule^index\.php$-[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./newsitein/project/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how to change it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled on the remote server?

Comment: Update once your `Permalink` from wordpress back admin. That will rewrite your rules. and will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush your Permalinks as Akshay stated.

To do this...

- Go to Settings->Permalinks in your Wordpress Admin area
- Scroll down and click Save Changes (even if you haven't changed anything).

They should now work.

It's a very common issue!

Comment: Is your site live? Can we have a look at the menu in question?

Answer (score 0):

In such circumstances it usually helps to change the permalink structure in the backend, save, and change it back to whatever you'd like. This rewrites the .htaccess with the new link structure.

Also, there might be a typo in your htaccess on the second last line since line 3 and the second last line are different - the DOT.

```
RewriteBase /newsite.in/project/
```

vs

```
RewriteRule ./newsitein/project/index.php [L]
```

Comment: i did it but still its not working. thanks for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps:

1. Check if mod_rewrite is enable on your server.You can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server)
2. When you moved your server make sure you update siteurl and home link
3. Update the permalink from Settings->Permalinks on your wordpress dashboard

Also your permalink is not formatted properly i think.Here is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /newsite.in/project/
RewriteRule^index\.php$-[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./newsite.in/project/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

You missed a `.` on `RewriteRule ./newsite.in/project/index.php [L]`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. how to check if mod_rewrite is enabled in server?

Comment: Did you follow all 3 steps ?

Comment: i cant able to change my apache2.conf file,permission is denied

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

Go to Settings => Permalinks

In Permalink Settings page

select post name and save it again ..and see if it's working. If not working go to step 2

Step 2

check httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Rewrite base is one of the importent thing that you need to check.. 
   in below site it's root "RewriteBase / "

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In youe case it should be "RewriteBase /newsite.in/" if your wordpress is located folder is located in newsite.in  folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /newsite.in/
RewriteRule^index\.php$-[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./newsitein/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If this is not working , Go to step 3

Step 3

check your site folder structure..

to do that save below code to test.php and upload to site's root folder

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?> 

browse it like http://sitename.com/test.php
seach "DOCUMENT_ROOT" , it should be display like below..


DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/apache2/public_html

In this your WordPress folder should be in public_html
```

reference : http://www.online-ebooks.info/article/wordpress_Permalink_is_not_working_after_migration.html

Comment: thank you for your response. Its working now http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-error-please-help?replies=17 i have referred this link and its working now.