# My .htaccess is not redirecting me to my public folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create a php framework. I am following this [tutorial](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/). But my `.htaccess` is not working. I have enabled my htaccess. But it is still not working. My `.htaccess` file is supposed to redirect me to the `index.php` folder, but it is not doing anything. Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I revise this?

Comment: might want to proofread your title next time. :P

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: I did. It works. It is enabled.

Comment: @eddard.stark You have not defined any redirection flags. Right now it rewrites internally.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: this is in my root folder of the project

Comment: if i type localhost in my browser then it shows what is in my root folder. It is not going to the public folder where the index.php resides.

Comment: Comment out both `IfModule` lines and see how it behaves.

Comment: I suspect your mod_rewrite is disabled. You should check if mod_rewrite is enabled at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server