# Htacces url rewriting not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have been trying to figure urlrewriting out. And i am still not really getting it i think.
So i tried this:

```
Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/? index.php
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ forum.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ forum.php?catagory=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^login/? loginpage.php
RewriteRule ^register/? registerpage.php
RewriteRule ^servers/? servers.php
RewriteRule ^profile/? profile.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   profile?user=$1
RewriteRule ^members/? memebers.php
```

And i clearly did not work, my page won't even load normal any more

When i use the normal url:

```
forum/?catagory=test
```

And this works very good and will show me everything. I don't get why the url rewriting is not working! Even tried a generator and some things else. It won't work

Comment: do you have `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /`

Comment: First thing, yes. Second thing i added now, but it didn't help.

Comment: What happens if you go to `/forum/test`? you get a 404 error or does forum.php load with no category?

Comment: @Nytrix: Do you have .htaccess inside `/forum/` folder also?

Comment: @anubhava there is no such folder. It is the rewriting to forum.php

Comment: Like @JonLin said, if it load without category, check out if your URL parameter is taken into consideration by your forum.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `MultiViews` option off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ forum.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ forum.php?catagory=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: I added my whole .htacces in the question. The page test.com/forum/test does not work. I get this: http://prntscr.com/5drsb8. I should get something like this: http://prntscr.com/5drsg3

Comment: ok looks like problem is not getting your css/js. That is due to your use of relative links for css/js/images. You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: I will try that! The only weird thing is, if i type it out normaly:  "test.com/forum/?catagory=test" that works fine.

Comment: It kind of did not work, you are right about that it is getting the  css/js/pictures from the wrong thing: http://prntscr.com/5dru84 . But your answer didn't do the trick..

Answer (score 0):

First, did you turn the RewriteEngine On?
Second, does the rewrite module is enabled? Do a `phpinfo();` to check it out and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server).

This way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ forum.php
RewriteRule ^forum/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ forum.php?catagory=$1 [L]
```

This page can help you: [URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: I have the engine on and it is enabled: as is said that "/forum/?catagory=test" works. I tried your code, i still isn't working.

Comment: Do you have an error output in your log that can help?

Comment: Yes i do i get for everything i load an error that it is unable to load: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "