# Wordpress pages or posts give 404-error - .htaccess looks ok

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Really desperate now, I uploaded my wordpress-installation onto my server and changed site-url and home-url in mysql. Now I am able to access my start page and wordpress-backend, but I cannot access pages or posts, I get an 404 error "site not found".

I tried to edit my .hcaccess, which now looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Nothing changed, even after server-reboot. I even changed permission for .htaccess to "777" - again nothing. Also tried to save url-settings in wordpress-backend without any succes. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is the issue still present if you set your permalinks to "Default" ?

Comment: yes, it works if I set it as default. But if I set it as postname after that, error shows up again

Comment: Well then, your server's rewrite module is probably not turned on. :) Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Comment: thanks, AllowOverride module is acitvated on my CentOS Server, i replaced all "AllowOverride None" with "AllowOverride All" in my httpd.conf - but still I cannot acces sites and pages :-(