# Codeigniter URLnot found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using `Codeigniter` framework in `PHP`. My website is on apache server. Path: `/var/www/example.com/public_html`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

But still I am getting this error on accessing this page: `www.example.com/test/wallet`:

> The requested URL /test/wallet was not found on this server.

**SCREEN SHOT**

[image]

**When I use `www.example.com/index.php/test/wallet`, then it's working...**

Comment: Check your controller file and methods. Can you share us controller codes? Do you use CodeIgniter v3?

Comment: Have you changed `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `config.php`? It looks like your .htaccess is attempting to remove the index.php from the URL.

Comment: `example.com/index.php/test/wallet` URL is working?

Comment: Begin from: does anything work ? :)

Comment: @Bora: Yes. That URL is working

Comment: It's `$config['index_page'] = '';` in my config file

Comment: Can you try following `.htaccess` please? `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Bora: No. It's same error.

Comment: By the way, it is strange condition `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)` - index.php or public or .txt - at the start

Comment: change your last line from  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1  to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: @Nassim: No. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Does the server allow rewriting? Check phpinfo() output if that module is loaded. Note that this is not a test for all setups, but if it does not show there maybe good to look in that direction. Some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all of your `.htaccess` setting are correct. I used @Nassim's solution.

Originally, Problem was with the configurations in `apache2.conf` file. I just set AllowOverride All in `/var/www` and activated rewrite on server by this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then I restarted my server: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Thanks to every1 for support.

Answer (score 1):

this is my .htaccess that works on both wamp and live linux server running Centos + Apache  and Ubuntu +apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path-to-code-igniter-directory/index.php/$1 [L]

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I also made a video on how to do this here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-4VkR54vLU

(skip to 28:50 to see the .htaccess .I also put it in the description under the video)

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

problem is with your URL rewrite.

place this outside application folder

File name = **.htacess**

in side

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No. Still it's not working. Can you please check edited question?

Comment: if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you