# index.php as a parameter in the url of laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I discovered that any laravel website is accessible with index.php as a parameter.

This is a big problem, index.php in url parameter breaks all images.
Look at a real example to understand what I mean:

http://www.example.com/main-thing/sightseeing 
http://www.example.com/index.php/main-thing/sightseeing

Googlebot read some urls with index.php as a parameter of url. This has effect to breaks all images when someone get access to the website from google search with index.php.

Also, this is a bad seo practice because produce duplicate content.

What is the best way to fix that?

Comment: Isn't this a .htaccess problem? I use CodeIgniter (Same mechanism). WHen i visit it with index.php in the url then everything is still working fina as all the links point to URL's without the index.html. I think there may be something wrong with your configuration too. I have no experience or knowledge on Laravel tough.

Comment: This is a .htaccess problem - to be fair, it seems the default .htaccess that ships with laravel allows this

Comment: I will use `Disallow: /*index.php*` in the `robots.txt` to fix the problem with google. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be fixed with [nginx rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). Using the bellow rule redirect all urls with `index.php` parameter to the `original laravel route url`

```
location /index.php {
      rewrite ^/index.php(.*)$ http://$server_name$1;
}
```

Also I've put the follow to the `robots.txt`

```
Disallow: /*index.php*
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `.htaccess` file provided with Laravel in your webroot or public folder?

If not, try putting this in a `.htaccess` file in your public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Directly taken this `.htaccess` from Laravel GitHub.

Also, you might need to check if the rewrite mod is enabled for your webserver.

Reference [How to check whether mod_rewrite is enable on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I use nginx for the webserver

Answer (score -1):

Also you can do this simply......

1.Open apache\conf\httpd.conf and search for this line

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
 2.then remove [#] and save,then restart apache