# The acess to another route => 404 Not found apache , laravel 5.4

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5.4

I just set up my composer and install a new laravel 5.4 project, and i set up a virtual host for apache server .
The virtual Host configuration 
[image: Te virtual host configuration]

And the host file : 

[image]

The home page `laravel.app` of the new application working fine 
But when i add a new view and i set a route for it like example :

```
//This is The default Home page route
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
// This is the new Route
Route::get('/hello',function(){
    return view('hello'); // I created another view with the name hello.blade.php  

});
```

When i try to access to it using the link `laravel.app/hello` i get this error :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /hello was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.18
>   (Ubuntu) Server at laravel.app Port 80

I want to mention that my os is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `<Directory>` is completly wrong inside the hosts file...

Comment: i can delet it cuz i lately added it but still the same problem

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` installed and active and exists the `.htaccess` file inside the public folder?

Comment: @Philipp as you can see i deleted it but it still the same .

Comment: The .htaccess exist in the public folder but the first thing `mod_rewrite` i didn't understand.

Comment: mod_rewrite is an apache module, which allows you to use pretty urls. Basically the configuration in your .htaccess file moves every request to an file which doesn't exists to the index.php file.

Comment: `AllowOverride All` in your httpd config for that vertial host. Check file ownership too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled or not. Use [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891317/1592845).

Second Place a `.htaccess` file in `.../public` with the following contents:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Checkout that [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration)

Comment: about your [question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10891317/1592845) i didn't find the line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in `apache2.conf` file

Comment: i activated `mod_rewrite` using `sudo a2enmod rewrite` now everything you said it's done but it's still the same problem.

Comment: The regarded answer of the question, is talking, mainly, about checking the existence of the mod_rewrite from `phpinfo()` output. However, did you restart Apache?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` exist in the `phpinfo() Loaded Modules ` .

Comment: What about the `.htaccess`?

Comment: If your `.htaccess` is placed in the correct path and it has the correct code regarded in the answer. So there is only one probability. Your view file `hello.blade.php` **is not** created in the `views` folder next to `welcome.blade.php`