# Redirect an entire site in CodeIgniter does not work

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I need to **redirect** an entire site to a specific controller (**under_construction**), but I do not want to put in all the pages a script to redirect.

I think, I might be able to do it in the `.htaccess` or in the `routes` of CodeIgniter.
In the *.htaccess* I do not know how to work with `regex` or how to do it.

With `routes` I have tried the following:

```
$route['index.php/test'] = "under_construction";
```

But this doesn't work. Does not shows any response, doesn´t do anything of 
that I expected, that all pages go to the `under_construction` controller.
I want to make this for a lot of controllers. Is there an easy way of doing this with `regex`?

Comment: looks like you want redirect all your controllers to under construction page? you can use 'hooks'.

Comment: @ichadhr yes, that is what I want, redirect all my controllers to under construction page, but I do not know how use hooks

Comment: Including `index.php` in routes is wrong. Please check the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php/under_construction$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/index.php/under_construction [L,R=302]
```

You really want to use .htaccess for best performance, and the 302 redirect says, "This redirect isn't permanent, so try the same request URI later".

Comment: I do this, but when I enter to a page know, it shows it

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on your server? Is the cache cleared?

Comment: how can I know that??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Comment: I have a trouble now, the image doesn´t see

Comment: Try to add a line before RewriteRule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images [NC]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152637/discussion-between-mary-and-brian-gottier).

Answer (score 0):

With routing, you can do something like this. In `APPATH.'config/routes.php'`:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'wanted/controller/method';
```

Set this route just after default ones (that came with installation).

Comment: Imagine for a minute the duplicate content penalization by Google whenall of your pages look the same...

Comment: You are right. Best would be to set variable in `index.php` file and check in, say, `APPPATH.'core/MY_Controller.php` for such a constant and load that specific landing page.

Comment: How is that any different than your routing solution?

Comment: I meant actually of redirecting (or remapping) to specific `controller/method`. maybe better redirect since response status can be set. And answer here is just to show usability of routes not seen as best solution. I would go with your one probably.