# htaccess unable to remove .php extension on Godaddy Linux

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know am re requesting the question which are already asked before but i tried all the posts and did all the research but still am unable to over come the problem i tried to put the below second snip first to htaccess in www directory and as well as folder directory [the link of the page](http://elmorfeo.com/snoozi-cut/product1) later i added the small snip it to the htaccess also but still its not working very disappointed my hosting provider is Godaddy  [if i add .php it works](http://elmorfeo.com/snoozi-cut/product1.php)

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

second

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.elmorfeo\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: Perhaps `mod-rewrite` isn't enabled on your server.

Comment: @starkeen How can i do that thanks for the reply

Comment: Read this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Comment: i see godaddy says it is enabled on all linux hosting https://in.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-use-mod-rewrite-899 still i will check the above link

Comment: i added like this to my root directory file of htaccess 

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

    <Directory "htaccess">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>` not working still

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Is `snoozi-cut` a real directory?

Comment: SORRY FOR LATE REPLY both places

Answer (score 0):

Following one works for me

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but still it show 404 error http://elmorfeo.com/snoozi-cut/product1

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that was all the above written ware correct but godaddy Cpanel there is no option to show hidden files i accessed it via ftp i found the original the correct htaccess file i did the changes there problem solved