# How do I solve incorrect MIME types being served on appended URLs?

Tags: php, html, apache, mime-types

I'm running a basic website used to practice php and some other things both locally with WAMP and on a hosted server with LAMP, both running with their default setups. I've been searching for hours to find a solution to this issue, and come across many topics with suggestions but these all seem to be related to files not being served properly at all. In my case, all the file types (css, js, images) are served as they should as long as I don't append the URL with anything.

For example; if I type 'local/index.php' as the URL the page loads as it should, with css, scripts and images being served with the right file type.
[Correct GET responds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9U6P.jpg)

However, if I append the URL and go to 'local/index.php/' the page loads but all files in the GET request are served with type html (except for the google fonts stylesheet): [Screenshot with incorrect file types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM2ud.jpg)

Both my local environment and online version have this issue.

I've tried adding an .htaccess file like some threads suggested, which wasn't there by default. I've checked the mime types file, which seemed to have the settings that people suggested to check for. I've tried adding these lines to the httpd.conf:

AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js

I'm getting this on all browsers I've tested (chrome, firefox, IE), and also tested on my mobile phone in case it was a client sided issue, but all with the same result.

If anyone could tell me what's going wrong I would greatly appreciate it! If you need more (specific) info let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: All right, I'm feeling rather stupid now. I was referring to file locations with "./dir/file" because before I had read that "./" refers to the root directory. So my href on my style.css file was "./css/style.css", and never suspected that to be wrong because all my files were loading properly until the URL got extended. Simply changing the href to "../css/style.css" (and replacing "./" with "../" for all other files) fixed my issue of getting the wrong content-type.

Comment: `local/index.php/` is idiomaticaly wrong. Paths ending with `/` are directories. Even Google can't handle this case (https://www.google.cz/favicon.ico/). The MIME type is probably your default, check `DefaultType`, see https://serverfault.com/a/265357.

Comment: Check the requested URLs of your resources for the normal and `/` case. Do they differ? Do you use mod_rewrite to serve them?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The requested URLs seem to be the same for both for the resources, except for the page file itself which just matches the URL. You just mean the the URLs shown in the 'Network' tab > Headers in the Firefox Developer tool right? I don't know if I'm 'using' mod_rewrite (sorry, I know basically nothing about any of this server / directory configuration stuff), but I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334688/9308871   It returned true so should be enabled, is that what you asked? Also last dumb question, where can I see the DefaultType? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: The SO answer you mentioned only check, if mode_rewrite is enabled, not being used. The DefaultType would be somewhere in your config files, their location depend on your system. To be honest, I have no idea, what is wrong. It is very rare to need to request files as if they were folders. Why do you need it? As I have already written, neither Google supports this on their website.

Comment: I kind of stumbled upon it by accident. I was following along with a tutorial on making a login system that was returning feedback within the URL. Although I'm pretty sure I made a mistake and used a forward slash instead of an ? (the tutorial uses /signup.php?signup=empty) and I may have used signup.php/signup=empty. Not sure as I cannot see the old states my file was in. After checking with just appending a '/' I noticed the files  didn't get served with the correct content type anymore. Checked to see if other sites work with it and they did, so I assumed something was wrong in my config.

Comment: But in case you had missed my edit. Nothing was 'wrong' in the end either, because I foolishly used "./" instead of "../" in file path references, which for reasons unknown to me worked unless I appended the url with a forward slash. Now that I've corrected that, "local/index.php/" works properly too, and all the files are served with the correct content-type like on other web pages.