# changed .htaccess and permalink now everything besides homepage 404s

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I added this code to my .htaccess file to get rid of index.php, but now all the pages 404 (the hyperlinks are mapped to the correct url)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i set up my permalinks using http://1.1.1.1/%postname%/

what are the next steps in order to troubleshoot this issue?

can anyone provide me with a rewrite link and where that file may be located (I don't fully understand the other similar posts as they all wrote their own rewrite rules, where would I find that file?)

I have already installed monkeyman rewrite analyzer, but don't know where to start troubleshooting from there.

Any links or information is helpful, even if is not a direct solution to the problem, I will post my solution when completed.

Comment: Are you using Apache? And if so, do you definitely have mod_rewrite enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10891317/4043746

Comment: I’m on Apache (httpd) and mod rewrite is enabled